# Does IBM Dataworks support CSV delimiters?

Tags: ibm-cloud, dataconnect

Does the IBM DataWorks Data Load API support CSV files as input source?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is *yes*. To accomplish this, you have provide the structure of the file in the request payload.  This is explained in the API documentation [Creating a Data Load Activity](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/dataworks1/index-gentopic1.html#t_data_load_create).  This an excerpt of the documentation:

> Within the columns array, specify the columns to provision data
>   from. If Analytics for Hadoop, Amazon S3, or SoftLayer Object Storage
>   is the source, you must specify the columns. If you specify columns,
>   only the columns that you specify are provisioned to the target...

The Data Load application included in DataWorks is provided just as an example and assumes the input file has 2 columns, the first being an INTEGER and the second one a VARCHAR.

**Note:** This question was [answered on *dW Answers*](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/184348/dataworks-supported-csv-delimiters.html) by user emalaga.